# Best way to embed calendar invites links in the body of an email

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, microsoft-word-365

We use Microsoft 365.

One of our departments wants to send emails to people outside our organization. The body of the emails will contain a lot of information about different meetings and activities that they have planned for the months ahead. What they want to have is links at the end of the description of an event, saying for example "if you plan to attend, please click here".

That "here" should action a calendar invite reply. From there, it should be the typical thing that we have done for ages when someone emails us a calendar invite, and we reply Yes, No, Tentative, then the reply goes to the sender, and the calendar event gets updated with the replies received.

So basically instead of sending 10 old-school calendar invites, one per each of the events, they want to have the calendar invites embedded in the body of a single email, then people can reply from there.

I hope I made myself clear, and I hope someone has done this already and can share the best way to do it.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Something like this is probably what you want:   https://www.intercom.com/help/en/articles/2688205-outlook-calendar-app-book-meetings-with-your-leads

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative method that works more broadly with Outlook and other calendar programs. An Internet calendar (iCalendar) attachment or a link to an iCalendar file can be added to the message body. When the recipient opens the attachment or clicks the link, the event is added to his or her calendar program.

Note:  Unlike Outlook meeting requests, when using iCalendar attachments and links you do not receive confirmations when people accept or decline.

[Create an Add to calendar link in an email message - Microsoft Support.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-an-add-to-calendar-link-in-an-email-message-34f8ea28-322a-4867-b423-2998f9634e59#:%7E:text=%20Create%20an%20Add%20to%20calendar%20link%20in,a%20link%20to%20the%20message%20body%20See%20More.)

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks, Soki. Sadly this doesn't work. Not receiving confirmations when people accept or decline already goes against what's required. Still I gave it a test to see how it works. I created two events, and forwarded them as ical to my Gmail account. I got the invites and added them to my Gmail calendar. Like you said, I never received a confirmation on my work email, I guess because there are no invitees on the events. Once I invited my Gmail account to each event, obviously two invitations were sent, which also is not what's required.

Comment: There may not be a way for the Outlook client to implement this feature directly.
When a meeting invitation occurs, an email will be automatically sent to the attendees after they are added.